# PHP ImagePNG creates just a 33 Byte File

Tags: php, image, png

Well, as I am not into the GD Libary and Image functions in PHP I am a bit stuck... In fact, the same function has no Problems with creating JPEG images from the uploaded files - but it's stuck on png... All I get is a 33 byte file with the right filename and destination - of course the original image exists and is uploaded just fine...

```
$altesBild=ImageCreateFromPNG("$PicPathIn"."$bild"); 
$neuesBild=imagecreatetruecolor(300,$neueHoehe);
$neuesBildHeader=imagecreatetruecolor(966,$neueHoeheHeader);  
imagecopyresampled($neuesBild,$altesBild,0,0,0,0,300,$neueHoehe,$breite,$hoehe);
imagecopyresampled($neuesBildHeader,$altesBild,0,0,0,0,966,$neueHoeheHeader,$breite,$hoehe);
ImagePNG($neuesBild,"$PicPathOut"."/thumbs/thumb_"."$bild",80);
ImagePNG($neuesBildHeader,"$PicPathOut"."/header/header_"."$bild",80);
```

Comment: Have you checked the values of `$neueHoehe`, `$neueHoeheHeader` etc?

Comment: My problem with 33 bytes fix imagesavealpha($neuesBildHeader, true) used after imagecopyresampled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a compression value between 0 and 9, as stated in the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) of the `ImagePNG` function.

Comment: This fixed my issue as well, thanks.  My problem was that imagepng() uses a quality value of 0 to 100 and I incorrectly assumed imagepng would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The value of 80 you use for compression is not defined: Here is an update of your code

```
$altesBild=ImageCreateFromPNG("$PicPathIn"."$bild"); 
$neuesBild=imagecreatetruecolor(300,$neueHoehe);
$neuesBildHeader=imagecreatetruecolor(966,$neueHoeheHeader);  
imagecopyresampled($neuesBild,$altesBild,0,0,0,0,300,$neueHoehe,$breite,$hoehe);
imagecopyresampled($neuesBildHeader,$altesBild,0,0,0,0,966,$neueHoeheHeader,$breite,$hoehe);
ImagePNG($neuesBild,"$PicPathOut"."/thumbs/thumb_"."$bild",8);
ImagePNG($neuesBildHeader,"$PicPathOut"."/header/header_"."$bild",8);
```

This should do the job.

Comment: The other guy was first but you are right as well of course ^^